Using lead() in Postgres with multiple columns
I have the following query:
select

calendar,
column1,
column2,
.
.
.
columnN,
count(some_value)/30 as some_value

from some_table
group by 1,2,...,N

Assuming my calendar is a date_trunc on 'month' and I want to use the lead() function to get the value from next year (12 months after the current value), how should my lead() syntax be?
I tried
lead(count(some_value)/30,12) OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2, ..., columnN ORDER BY calendar ASC)

but it does not work as expected.
What I have tested is selecting a single column and it does work. If I select multiple columns in does not.
sample output:



calendar
column1
column2
count
lead




01-01-23
Type A
a
1
30


01-01-23
Type B
a
3
34


01-02-23
Type A
b
2
25


01-02-23
Type B
a
5
51


01-03-23
Type A
b
4
45


01-03-23
Type B
b
10
37


01-04-23
Type B
b
6



01-05-23
Type A
b
15



01-06-23
Type B
a
14



01-07-23
Type B
b
4



01-08-23
Type A
b
5



01-08-23
Type B
a
2



01-09-23
Type A
b
32



01-09-23
Type B
b
32



01-10-23
Type B
a
41



01-11-23
Type B
b
44



01-12-23
Type B
a
32



01-01-24
Type A
a
30



01-01-24
Type B
a
34



01-02-24
Type A
b
25



01-02-24
Type B
a
51



01-03-24
Type A
b
45



01-03-24
Type B
b
37




The idea is to retrieve for a specific combination of calendar date, type from column 1 and category from column 2 the count value from the same month from the next calendar year

Could you provide some simple data and the expected output ?

What is count(some_value)/30 supposed to do?

@SelVazi edited the post to include some context

@Bergi it does some calculation that should be irrelevant to the issue I face. whether it is a simple count of an ID or whatever other aggregation it should not impact the result, right?
Just for reference I am calculating some kind of avg.

The problem with the lead(…, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY column1, column2, ..., columnN ORDER BY calendar ASC) appears to be that you don't actually have rows for all 12 months for all types in your example

So I should have actually rows for all the possible combinations for this to work properly? I see now! thank you very much. This at the same time explains why it does work if I select a single column.
Is there a way to work around this?

You could do a left join against generate_series expression for the desired timeframe

ty @Bergi. I wanted to avoid it but yes it seems to be the only possibility here

The alternative would be a self-join or subquery, instead of the lead() window function, to get the value for 12 months after the row.
